# ConcurrentDictionary and visibility

Tags: visibility, concurrentdictionary

I have read that ConcurrentDictionary only locks when writing, so the reads are lock free.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/01/08/9945809.aspx
*reads on the dictionary are performed in a lock-free manner*

But what about visibility, how do they ensure this when the reads are lock free?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of the MemoryBarrier ensures that the objects are 'published' for other threads. This does not require a lock.

Comment: thanks just have to understand it before using it. http://code.google.com/p/codesmith/source/browse/trunk/Templates/Frameworks/PLINQO/Source/CodeSmith.Data/Collections/ConcurrentDictionary.cs?r=1991